# how to insert the data-type property in the codeigniter form_dropdown?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have one Dropdown option with codeigniter

Codeigniter Code is

```
<?= form_dropdown('', array(
            'custom' => 'Custom',
            'tour_package' => 'Tour',
            'visa' => 'Visa'
       ),'','class="product_type"'); 
?>
```

but i want to **add new value of the datatype into the dropdown**.

**data-property='product_type'**

I need to show my souce code like this.

HTML Code

```
<select name="order[order_products][0][product_type]" class="product_type">
<option value="custom">Custom</option>
<option value="tour_package">Tour</option>
<option value="visa">Visa</option>
</select>
```

Jquery Code

```
$('input,select').each(function(){
   var property = $(this).attr('data-property');
   $(this).attr('name','order[order_products]['+current_counter+']['+property+']');

})
```

Comment: like this `<select name="order[order_products][0][product_type]" class="product_type" data-property="product_type">`?

Comment: Yes bro.that i want to show the value.

Comment: Hmm, so you want `data-property` as dynamic with selected value. Ex: `data-property="custom"`, `data-property="visa"` or `data-property="tour_package"`, right?

Comment: NO bro, I just want to add the data-type in the dopdown but now i fixed with the code like this <?= form_dropdown('', $option,'','class="product_type"data-property="product_type"'); ?> Thanks you so much for thinking.

Comment: I thought that may be you want dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With fourth segment, you can append attributes as much as you want.

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('', array(
            'custom' => 'Custom',
            'tour_package' => 'Tour',
            'visa' => 'Visa'
       ),'','class="product_type" data-property="product_type"'); 
?>
```